# EF Core Context always null in BaseController

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-3.1, dbcontext, onactionexecuting

I've a `BaseController` but when I call the functions from the child Controllers the Context is always `null`:

```cs
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly TheContext _tContext;
    public BaseController(TheContext tContext)
    {
        _tContext= tContext;
    }

    public BaseController() { }

    public void test()
    {
        var foo = _tContext.BAR;
    }
}
```

I've been dealing with this by passing the Context to the `BaseControler` function from the child controller.

However, I now need to use `OnActionExecuting()` as there is code I need to run on load for each controller which uses the `BaseController`, which means I can't pass it the initialized context from the child controller.

Comment: Have you tried using Dependency Injection?

Comment: `_tContext` is not accessible to classes derived from your `BaseController` because it is private. And why do you have two constructors?

Comment: I find inheritance is usually not the best pattern to use in cases like this. Methods like `test()` should be placed into a service that injects the context. Controllers that use the method should inject that service. Things that need to be done for each action should be placed in [action filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: @AlexeyChuksin I'm blind ,I thought I had, but was missing the ": base(tContext)" in the 
child controllers. Works now ty